# Теоретический вопрос по MVC и Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, mvc

В реальном времени через API подгружаются данные с другого сайта с помощью php кода. 
Есть html страница, на которой эти данные нужно отобразить при клике на кнопку "Отобразить данные". И вот появляется вопрос, вызвать этот код Аякс запросом или можно это через MVC как-то сделать, вызовом функции или ещё как-то ?

Comment: Одно другому не мешает.

Comment: Даже не так @Bim Bam путает теплое с мягким. Это MVC и AJAX - 2 разных понятия.  AJAX («Asynchronous Javascript And Xml») - это технология асинхронной погрузки данных. А MVC - это паттерн отделения данных от их представления. А что касается вопроса, то если нужно выводить данные без перезагрузки страницы, то ajax подходящий вариант. А если допустимо с перезагрузкой, то можно просто получать данные с аккумулирующей страницы POST запросом например.

Comment: @ArtResh так а файл с Ajax запросом где стоит разместить ?  В моделях ?

Comment: Если следовать MVC, то скрипт исполняющий ajax следует разместить на странице Вида. А обращаться за данными ему следует к контроллеру, который уже будет определять из какого источника ему получать данные